# Show why a question was closed in the revisions list

Tags: status-completed, feature-request, revisions-list

The revisions list shows when a question was closed and who by but not **why**. This would make it useful to see the complete history of a question.

**Clarification:** I'm talking about the revisions list not the actual page that displays the question. On contentious questions the post can be closed an reopened several times but the reasons are missing from the revisions page. Here are a few examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/184618/list
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1003841/list
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/184618/list

Imported from: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/209267-show-why-a-question-was-closed-in-the-revisions-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He suggests that the reason is shown in the list. Right now, the revision list simply shows that it was closed and by whom.

Currently:

```
Post Closed by EnderMB, Mehrdad, DJ, Marko, Adam Davis
```

Should Be:

```
Post Closed as "no longer relevant" by EnderMB, Mehrdad, DJ, Marko, Adam Davis
```

I think that adding the reason in the revision list could be useful.

Comment: Right! That's the example I *should* have given